# new transaction is waiting for open operation:react-native

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native

I am trying to import preloaded DB in React-native app but on a console, neither success nor failure message comes in. Please check attached image. Where I'm getting wrong?

tblCategory is table name ... DB name coming through Pragma query is main and file name is IDB_DB_New.sqlite

this IDB_DB_New.sqlite file is in www folder

`let db = SQLite.openDatabase( {name: 'tblCategory', createFromLocation : "IDB_DB_New.sqlite", location: 'Library'}, this.openCB, this.errorCB);`

**new transaction is waiting for open operation**

[image]

[image]